# Strange error with Invoke-Command : Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform

Tags: ubuntu, centos, powershell

Sometimes, When I try to execute a remote command in a PowerShell Session from PowerShell in Linux, I get this error:

> Invoke-Command : Windows Principal functionality is not supported on
>   this platform.

From PowerShell in Mac works fine, but with PowerShell in Linux doesn't.

From Ubuntu with:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.0.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    v6.0.1
OS                             Linux 4.4.0-1041-aws #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 15 22:18:17 UTC 2017
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

From CentOS with:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.0.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    v6.0.2
OS                             Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

If I try with Enter-PSSession I get always:

> Enter-PSSession : You are currently in a PowerShell PSSession and
>   cannot use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet to enter another PSSession.

And then, Invoke-Command works fine.

[image: Invoke-Command works after get an error from Enter-PSSession]

Comment: Seems a bug, I created https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6435